# Why does wait queue implementation wait on a loop until condition is met?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Lets consider a single processor scenario.

`wait_event_interruptible()` (or other wait APIs) wait in a loop until a certain condition is met.

Now, since linux has threads implemented as separate processes, I believe a false wake (where the `wait_event*` is woken up with the condition not met) is indicative of error in the program/driver.

Am I wrong? - Is there any valid scenario where such false wakes can happen and are used? In other words, why wait on the condition in a **loop** in `wait_event*` implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common use case for wait queues is with interrupts. Perhaps your kernel driver is currently waiting on three different conditions, each of which will be awoken with an interrupt.

This allows your kernel interrupt handler to just wake up all of the listeners, who can then determine among themselves if their particular condition has occurred, or if they should wake up.

Also, you can get spurious interrupts because interrupts can be shared and because of interrupts being deferred and coalesced.

---

*Adding some code and what not to try to be more explicit.*

I've written some code below that could be part of a kernel driver. The interrupt handler is simply going to wake up all of the listeners. However, not all of the listeners may actually be done. Both will be woken up by the same interrupt, but they will both look to see if their particular condition is done before continuing.

```
// Registered interrupt handler
static irqreturn_t interrupt_handler(void *private) {
    struct device_handle *handle = private;
    wake_up_all(&handle->wait);
}

// Some Kernel Thread
void program_a(struct device_handle * handle) {
    wait_event_interruptible(&handle->wait, hardware_register & 0x1);
    printk("program_a finished\n");
}

// Some other kernel thread
void program_b(struct device_handle * handle) {
    wait_event_interruptible(&handle->wait, hardware_register & 0x2);
    printk("program_b finished\n");
}
```

Comment: Can driver wait on multiple conditions? Isn't it that once the process is suspended because of the first wait, nothing else can execute? So I assume there can be atmost one wait?

Comment: I've added some code.. But a kernel module can have multiple threads executing on it at any one point in time.

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
#define __wait_event(wq, condition)                     \
do {                                    \
    DEFINE_WAIT(__wait);                        \
                                    \
    for (;;) {                          \
        prepare_to_wait(&wq, &__wait, TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);    \
        if (condition)                      \
            break;                      \
        schedule();                     \
    }                               \
    finish_wait(&wq, &__wait);                  \
} while (0)
```

(Besides the fact that the kernel is preemptive...)

I assume you're referring to the infinite 'for' loop above?
If so, the main reason it's there is this:

The code does not make any assumption about state once it's awoken. Just being awoken does *not* mean the event you were waiting upon has actually occurred; you *must* recheck. That's exactly what the loop achieves. If the 'if' condition comes true (which it should, in the normal case), it exits the loop, else (spurious wakeup) it puts itself to sleep again by calling schedule().

Answer (score 0):

Even in the single processor scenario, the kernel is preemptive, i.e. the control can be at any moment pass to other thread/process so the behavior is the same as multi-processor.
Good discussion on the lost-wait problem is here:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8144/print

Comment: Agreed that control can pass. But I don't see how the loop in 'wait_event' solves the synchronization issue described in the article. The loops seems to be more of a retry attempt..i just want to know why